# How to get automatically generated Firebase push ID from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app sends every message with a unique id (using push() method) so how can I get this id?

my code to send message :

```
String messageSenderRef = "Messages/" + messageSenderID + "/" + messageReceiverID;
        String messageReceiverRef = "Messages/" + messageReceiverID + "/" + messageSenderID;

        DatabaseReference userMessagesKeyRef = reference.child("Messages")
                .child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID).push();

        String messagePushID = userMessagesKeyRef.getKey();

        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
        messageTextBody.put("message",messageText);
        messageTextBody.put("type","text");
        messageTextBody.put("to",messageReceiverID);
        messageTextBody.put("from",messageSenderID);
        messageTextBody.put("time",time);
        messageTextBody.put("date",date);
        messageTextBody.put("isSeen",false);
        messageTextBody.put("messageID",messagePushID);


        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
        messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef + "/" + messagePushID,messageTextBody);
        messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef + "/" + messagePushID,messageTextBody);
```

My Firebase database node:

Firebase Node:

[image: firebase node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the value of `messageID` field, then you should create a reference that points to the `cG6v...PXi1` node and use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messagesRef = db.child("Messages");
DatabaseReference messageReceiverIdRef = messagesRef.child(messageSenderID).child(messageReceiverID);
messageReceiverIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String messageId = ds.child("messageID").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", messageId);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
-ND-fz....l2krv
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex. actually this method helped me to get the **messageID** but also I will have many messages in the node of  **messageReceiverID** so how this method actually work , is it get last message or how ?

Comment: Also , i would like to mention that I am using `if (position == userMessagesList.size()-1)` and `if (userMessagesList.get(position).isSeen())` to check **UserMessageSeenStatus**

Comment: Your question sounds like "How to get automatically generated firebase push id". And the solution is in my answer above. If you have any other question that derives from this one, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.